# Moving Ubuntu Server installation from flash drive to HDD via SSH

Tags: server, configuration, home-server

I am wanting to move my Ubuntu Server installation from the USB flash drive to a more permanent location on a HDD on my NAS. I initially installed Ubuntu Server on the USB drive as  a test but it has grown into a fully configured server.

The catch is that the server has no keyboard, monitor or dvd drive and is only accessible via ssh - so I think that makes something like Clonezilla unusable?

Apart from the USB drive there is also an internal HDD that contains a ZFS pool with a few bits on it and 2 more larger HDD on the way. I would like to move the USB drive setup to the current internal HDD and make it bootable, all using SSH.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With the USB drive plugged in you can copy all of the files on the drive to, say, `\root\`, and be almost all set. You may be able to chroot into `/root` and check things out.
2. But now the tricky part, you need to rename `/root` to `/` and reboot *simultaneously*. You can't do the rename before the reboot because at that point your target system will no longer be intact--its file system won't match its kernel and environment and you can't do anything after the reboot is issued.
3. Further, it would be almost crazy to rename and reboot simultaneously as the system is unusable if the new software won't run that particular hardware--you will be dead in the water.

This is why serial consoles are used. I suggest that you spend a few bucks for a serial card and add it to the server. That way you can do the final work from there and back things out if you try things that don't work.

---

Another idea is to run your new system as a virtual machine on the old one.